# Strange output with my as3 arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, null, indexof

So, I think my question should be fairly straightforward, I am just looking for a little clarification on why I'm getting these seemingly odd results when I try to use the Array.indexOf method with null. Here's my code:

```
var myArray:Array = new Array(20);
trace(myarray.indexOf(null)); //output: -1
trace(myarray[0] == null); //output true
```

So, it looks like the elements of an array are defaulted to null when a length constructor parameter is initialized, but why does indexOf(null) not return 0?

Comment: I could be wrong but I think `null` is a tricky thing to work with, especially with such functions. I would try swapping the lines (i.e. tracing the condition before tracing the function) and seeing if it makes a difference.

Comment: @puggsoy, the output is the same regardless of the order the statements come in (I would hope that it would be... I would be disturbed if the == operator modified my array to make indexOf work somehow :P )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> elements of an array are defaulted to null

Nope. It's a popular belief in [JS](http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html) & [AS3](http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/2011/01/as3-undefined-vs-null/). A property, when it has no definition, is **undefined**.

Besides, anyone implementing the indexOf function, would obviously check if the value to be searched is **null** before actually starting to search.

Also I think you are looking for this :

```
var myArray:Array = new Array(20);
trace(myArray.indexOf(undefined)); //output: 0
trace(myArray[0] == null); //output true
```

Answer (score 2):

If only a single numeric parameter is passed to the Array constructor, it is assumed to be length and it is converted to an integer by using the Integer() function. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000737.html

```
var myArray:Array = new Array(20);
trace(myArray.length); //output: 20
```

As for the difference between `null` and `undefined` you can check this http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/2011/01/as3-undefined-vs-null/

Comment: ooh, +1 for the null vs undefined link, I didn't realize as3 was so javascripty